# MeCab 形態素解析の結果が意図した通り表示されない

Tags: python, mecab

MeCabでリスト形式のデータを形態素解析したいのですが、頭の一文字だけ表示されてしまいます。

```py
test = ['国語が得意です。','算数が得意です。','理科が苦手です。','社会が苦手です。','英語が苦手です。']
words_list = []

#形態素解析（名詞・動詞に絞る）
t = MeCab.Tagger()
for s in test:
   s_parsed = t.parse(s[0])
   words_s = []
   for line in s_parsed.splitlines()[:-1]:
      word = line.split("\t")[0]
      if word == 'EOS':
         break
      else:
         pos = line.split('\t')[1]
         slice = pos.split(',')
         if (slice[0] in ['名詞']):
            if (slice[0] in ['動詞']):
               words_s.append(slice[6])
            else:
               words_s.append(word)
   words_list.append(words_s)

print(words_list)
```

結果

```
[['国'], ['算'], ['理'], ['社'], ['英']]
```

Comment: `s_parsed = t.parse(s[0])` とされていますが、`s_parsed = t.parse(s)` とすれば良いかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事解決いたしました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
s_parsed = t.parse(s[0])
```

`s[0]`は1文字目ですよね。`s`が`'国語が得意です。'`であれば、`s[0]`は`国`になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！`s[0]`をリストの一行目と勘違いしておりました。